# How can I define a key mapping which involves a control character?

Tags: key-bindings

in normal mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> scrolls the buffer itself. from `:h CTRL-E`

> CTRL-E ...........................................* Scroll window *
>   [count] lines downwards in the buffer.

I would like to remap that so when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> vim performs 3 x <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.
I've tried

- `map <Ctrl-e> 3<Ctrl-e>`
- `nnoremap <Ctrl-e> 3<Ctrl-e>`
- `nnoremap ^E 3^E`

but these have no effect, how can I perform this mapping?

Comment: `:help key-notation`

Comment: @romainl  I was looking for that exact section in the documentation when I asked the question. I remember seeing it but couldn't remember how to get to it!

Comment: I knew it had `ctrl-k` but when I tried `:helpgrep ctrl-k` I got nothing. Helpgrep is case sensitive so I should have used `:helpgrep ctrl-k\c`

Answer (score 4):

The reason why

```
:nnoreamp ^E 3^E
```

Doesn't work is because `^E` is *two* separate characters. You can tell because you have to hit the arrow keys twice to move backwards past it. So you are really remapping <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> to <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>, which is probably not what you want to do, especially since `^` doesn't take a number argument.

When you use a digraph, this is displayed as two characters, but it is a *single* character, which you can tell because backspace and arrow keys treat it as a single character. The other way you can tell is because vim will (*probably*) display it as a different color. For me, this digraph appears blue, but it might be different for you depending on your setup.

The answer you came up with *works* but it isn't the ideal way or the idiomatic way. A better way of entering a digraph is with `<C-v>`, rather than `<C-k>`. With `<C-k>` you have to hit ctrl+e twice, but if you were to use `<C-v>` you could just hit ctrl+e one time and it would work. So that would look like

```
:nnoremap<space><C-v><C-e><space>3<C-v><C-e>
```

Which is a little easier than what you were doing. An even *better* way (IMO) is to use an ASCII literal, rather then a digraph. I prefer this method since:

- It keeps your `.vimrc` tidier.
- It is easier to understand what is pressed vs what is sent to vim.
- It's more readable.
- It avoids nasty unicode unprintables.

You were close with your initial try of

```
:nnoremap <Ctrl-e> 3<Ctrl-e>
```

You just got one minor detail wrong. `<Ctrl-e>` does not describe any keystroke that vim can understand. You should have written

```
:nnoremap <C-e> 3<C-e>
```

Comment: nice explanation, thanks. the ascii literal sounds nice as it might be something a bit more non-vim specific. what would be an example of an ascii literal?

Comment: @the_velour_fog No, using `<C-v>` is vim specific. It's just how vim handles keys with modifiers. There's also `<M-v>` (meta + v, usually alt) and `<S-v>` (shift + v). In other languages, it would probably be a hex code corresponding to the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), although it varies from language to language.

Comment: interesting, I just entered the `^E` digraph character into a file using vim, then opened the file with `hexedit`. the character in hex is `05` , from the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) it is called `ENQ` where [this explains that ENQ is an old way of referencing `Ctrl-e`](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090429210551AAfL2z9)

Comment: If you find that interesting, you'd also find it interesting that ctrl+ `a, b, c, ...` is `01, 02, 03, 04 ...`. Also, if you take any valid key and do it again but with `alt` down, it adds 128 (hex 80) to the ASCII value.

Comment: nice, with `Ctrl + a,b,c` (I need to hit C-b twice because Im running tmux) I get that result. But if I open a file in vim as UTF-8 and press `Ctrl-v`,then `alt + a` I get two characters. in vim it looks like `^[` and then a normal `a`. In hexedit its `1B` and `61` . from ascii table, `ESC` and letter `a`, weird...

Answer (score 1):

in the end this worked

- hit `:nnoremap`

  - enter command line mode
- hit `<space>`

  - to put a space between `nnoremap` and control char about to come
- hit `<C-k>`

  - to enter "digraph"? mode see more info see: `:h c_CTRL_k`
- enter `Ctrl-e` twice to generate special non-printed character which appears as `^E` but if you manually type `^E` in your mapping it doesn't seem to work?

at this point the command line or buffer looks like (note: the digraph generated character sequences appear a different color to normal text and they are treated as a single character not `^` and `E`.)

```
:nnoremap ^E
```

add a 3 and another digraph generated `^E` till command line or buffer looks like

```
:nnoremap ^E 3^E
```